# Prove that a difference of normal probability densities is non-negative

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Let $a$,$b$ be positive real numbers such that $a<b$. Show that $f(x)$ is non-negative for all $x>0$ where

$f(x)= \phi(a-x)-\phi(b+x)$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal PDF.

So far I have that $f(0)>0$ and that

$f'(x)=(a-x)\phi(a-x)+(b+x)\phi(b+x)$

and then I get stuck

Comment: $a-x < a < b < b+x$ and $\Phi$ is an increasing function, so ...

Comment: Using the words "Equation is non-zero" is not right.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem. Hopefully, it makes more sense.

Comment: Greg, Aryabhata's point (which he could have made more clear) was that *equations* are neither negative nor positive nor zero, but *functions* can be any of these.  The title should read: "Prove the following *function* is non-negative".

Comment: @Antonio Vargas Done

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Yes, that is what I meant. I should have read the whole question, instead of just the title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a<b$ and $a,b,x>0$ we have $-b-x < a - x < b + x$, or $|a-x| < |b+x|$, so that $-(b+x)^2/2 < -(a-x)^2/2$, and hence that

$$
\sqrt{2\pi} \phi(b+x) = e^{-(b+x)^2/2} < e^{-(a-x)^2/2} = \sqrt{2\pi} \phi(a-x).
$$

Thus $f(x) = \phi(a-x) - \phi(b+x) > 0$.

Comment: I had deleted this answer since Robert's comment gets right to the point, but I figure I might as well leave it.

Comment: There should not have been CDF's in the question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Greg, I have edited my answer to reflect your new question.  Is it satisfactory?